# How to determine which command line options gcc passes to ld by default?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, binutils

Consider the hello world C program:

**hello.c**:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

If I call:

```
$ gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
```

It will produce an ELF Relocatable File **hello.o**

If I then call:

```
$ gcc hello.o -o hello            [1]
```

It will link hello.o with ld and produce an ELF Executable File **hello**

However if I call ld directly `[2]` instead of `[1]`:

```
$ ld hello.o -o hello             [2]
```

I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `puts'
```

gcc must be passing other options to ld (to link the C library for example).

Is there anyway to determine exactly what the command-line gcc is passing through to ld in command `[1]` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use `gcc -v hello.o -o hello` to get the link line.  For your example on my ubuntu machine, I get this link line (edited to be multiline for readability):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/collect2
--build-id
--eh-frame-hdr
-m elf_x86_64
--hash-style=gnu
-dynamic-linker
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-o hello
-z relro
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/crtbegin.o
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib
-L/lib/../lib
-L/usr/lib/../lib
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../.. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
hello.o
-lgcc
--as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed 
-lc
-lgcc
--as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crtn.o
```

Note that `collect2` is just an alias for `ld`.

Comment: It seems on my Ubuntu 12.10 64 box `collect2` is not a simple alias for `ld`.  `collect2` is an executable- whereas `ld` is a sym link to `ld.bfd` which is a symlink to `hardened-ld` which is a perl script.  No idea what is going on there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean literal alias.  You'll find that if you run the same command with `ld` instead it will work the same, though.  Docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gccint/Collect2.html

Comment: What is the difference between `collect2` and `ld`? Could not understand easily after reading the gccint.

Comment: They are literally the same binary.

Answer (score 2):

For oneline lovers:

```sh
echo "int main(void) {}" | gcc -o /dev/null -v -x c - &> /dev/stdout| grep collect | tr -s " " "\012"
```

Replace `-x c` with `-x c++` to get c++ flags.

Can be used also with clang, but in such case you should grep for `/usr/bin/ld`